# What is the best location for storing data across applications

Tags: android, storage

I have applications A and B (and some day C).  Both need read/write access to some data.  It's not sensitive, but at the same time I don't want it to be in the users face (like their download folder or anything).  I also need to support phones with or without SD cards.  I also have no idea what order the applications are installed (A then B, or B then A).

What's the best way to store this?

SharedPreferences seem like a good idea, but from what I understand they can only really be defined with a shared package name, and if that package is A, then B won't be able to use them until A is installed.

Internal storage was my next idea, but I don't know what folders are appropriate for this.

Edit - Clarifying requirements:

Apps A, B, and C all use the same data and need to share it amongst themselves.  Whatever application is installed first should create this data and then all other applications should access that.  None of the applications requires any of the others to be installed.

Comment: Perhaps you should just use and store data in a common database. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: From that page: `Any databases you create will be accessible by name to any class in the application, but not outside the application.`  Or is there another mechanism that I missed?

Answer (score 3):

You cant get access to internal storage (unless your device is rooted) for cross-app file access, except for app's own internal cache/file directory(s).

in your case, there are two options i can recommend.

1. use [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to offer app's data to other apps.
2. use [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) (sd card) to save your data (not in app's cache
   directory) and let your apps read/write it independently

Comment: I was planning to answer to use a ContentProvider as well, but @Waqas has already suggested it so I'll just agree.

Comment: So every application (A, B, and C) supply a content provider?  Then if the user installs app C then app B, how does B know to use C's provider?

Comment: You need to make a query in order to read data from other app's content provider. So when the query is successful, it will return you **Cursor**, else **null**. That is how how you may know which app's data is available or not. Another way is to use PackageManager and verify if your required app is installed/available in the device or not.

Comment: if it is a simple data you just can to using shared preferences. http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html

Comment: @Dhamodharan You cannot. Shared preferences are application specific and cannot be shared among different applications.

Comment: why not? simple data like string values can share using shared pref but the restrictions are 1. You need to manage the package name 2. Now it is deprecated. Have you seen the blog I mentioned above?